# Access other Android Apps Reviews

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-developer-api

I am building an application in which I wanted to get the list of reviews, comments and ratings from Google Play Store of other Android apps.

Using Google Developer Play API I can get the reviews list for apps hosted by me but it struggling to find a way to get the reviews/comments list of others apps(not published by my account). Let me know if anyone had any idea about this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Get all reviews from any Google App.

https://still-plateau-10039.herokuapp.com/reviews?id=mytown.preschool

```
id={google-app-id}
```

This will return a json of

```
 [
id: "id",
userName: "Sonal Zade",
userImage: "user-image-h96/photo.jpg",
date: "April 15, 2017",
url: "url",
score: 5,
title: "",
text: "I have fun to play your games but the problem is that these games."
]
```

The service will return all the reviews on the app

Or simple host this locally
Source code of the service can be found at https://github.com/tohir87/googleplay-reviews

Comment: Is this based on web page crawling ?

Comment: Yes. Web page scrapping

Comment: Ok thanks and does is scrap from all countries stores at once or we have to call it one by one ?

Comment: It was extended from https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper. I just exposed it as a consumable Node service currently hosted on heroku.

Comment: @Tohir I need to get unresponded review list from google developers app and post a response from their account.is it possible  ?? pls answer this qn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185190/how-to-access-google-developer-api-in-android-app