# How to access google developer api in android app

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-developers-console

I am trying to develop an app which needs to access google developer API by using developer email.I have gone through official documentation.I don't understand much.I created client id by following this instructions.https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization
But for generating token they mentioned to call this API "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=...&client_id=...".I have client id but I don't know the value for redirect URI in case of android application.objective is I need to get all reviews of the app from developer credentials.Pls anyone help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what you are doing, you might find it useful to look at the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237872/android-publisher-api-without-oauth-of-developer-account  pls ans this