# Publisher API without oAuth of developer account

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-developers-console

I have some doubts. I stuck in that for a week. I am doing an app to get all reviews from a play store. It's for all end user who has an account in play store.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

This document specifies that I need to create oAuth and I need to link project id in my developer console
for accessing review API
I tried that and its working fine. But for all end user its odd for them to create OAuth and link project id into their dev console and then accessing my app
I don't get any solution
if anyone knows please reply

Comment: The way I see it, you are trying to retrieve all the posted content of the user from the play store?

Comment: yes.I am trying to get all reviews of an app in playstore from any developer account with their credentials.But in documentation they sepcified to create oAuth and i need to link project in that developer console.if its so no one access my app except  me